# Can a cosmological constant model inhomogeneities?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, universe, cosmological-constant

Consider the following zero-order approximation to the universe:

- Spacetime is perfectly homogeneous, and
- The cosmological constant is exactly zero.

This doesn't quite work. Neither assumption is true. There are two possible first-order corrections:

- Spacetime has some inhomogeneities, or
- The cosmological constant is small but non-zero.

In introductory textbooks we usually go by the latter, which gives a very good approximation to the real world. And only in advanced textbooks we add the effect of impurities.

My question is, what if we still keep a zero cosmological constant, but add small impurities? Would this also give a decent approximation? In other words, can a non-zero cosmological constant simulate impurities, and vice-versa?

As a proof of concept, consider the way planetary precession is studied. The standard method to compute, say, mercury's anomaly is to use Kepler with respect to the sun, and then add the secondary effect of other planets (and, if you want to get the number right, the effect of curvature). The way the effect of other planets is added is, one averages over their orbital position, so in effect they become continuous mass distributions (rings) instead of point particles. I could imagine how a similar setting could work at cosmological scales: all the impurities are averaged over space, and they give an effective constant mass distribution instead of point-like defects. So, to a very crude approximation, impurities could replicate the effect of a cosmological constant. Or not really?

Comment: I noticed no responses in over a month, so I thought I might try to help a bit. (1) I do not understand "zero-order approximation". (2) The assumption of homogeneity is usually applied to space, not space-time. If you clarify these two issues, what becomes of your question?

Comment: @Buzz Thanks! (1) "zero-order approximation" is a vague expression with no rigorous meaning. I just mean "first approximation that comes to mind, very simple and rough, but should yield a somewhat reasonable description, until we figure out how to improve it". (2) I'm not sure the distinction between "space" and "spacetime" is crucial here, since "curvature" also refers to spacetime rather than just space. But perhaps I'm being naive and you're right that this is the key aspect to resolving my question!

Comment: "'curvature' also refers to spacetime" Regarding a model of the universe and how it changes (usually explored by cosmologists as expansion these days)  the curvature variable is a scalar function which can have any real value (like 0 or any positive number) or imaginary (that is any real positive number times the square root of -1) value.  curvature of space time is represented by a tensor, which is more more complex than a scalar function. While the word curvature might apply to both, their meanings are completely different. The distinction is "crucial".